# How to use SQL sum if with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sum, case

```
| 1dist | 1result | 2dist | 2 result | 3dist | 3result|
|-------|---------|-------|----------|-------|--------|
|  5    |  MADE   |  NULL |   NULL   |  NULL | NULL   |
| 10    |  MISS   |  2    |   MADE   |  NULL | NULL   |
|  5    |  MADE   |  NULL |   NULL   |  NULL | NULL   |
| 20    |  MISS   |  5    |   MILL   |  2    | MADE   |
```

From this table I'm looking to sum the 1dist, 2dist, 3dist where the result columns = made.
The result I'm looking for in the example would be 5+2+5+2 = 14

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN 1result = MADE THEN 1dist) +
       SUM(CASE WHEN 2result = MADE THEN 2dist) +
       SUM(CASE WHEN 3result = MADE THEN 3dist)
FROM table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your query you just missing END and When you compare any string you must you used string inside single quote '

try this

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN 1result = 'MADE' THEN 1dist END) +
SUM(CASE WHEN 2result = 'MADE' THEN 2dist END) +
SUM(CASE WHEN 3result = 'MADE' THEN 3dist END)  As Final_Result
FROM Table_Name
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been working on this for 2 hours and I was missing the "END"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do it maybe there are better ways or more optimized, try this one,
i assume that table name is test.
just union all the pair columns

```
SELECT SUM(dist) AS sum, result 
FROM (
    SELECT [1dist] AS dist, [1result] AS result 
    FROM test 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT [2dist] AS dist, [2result] AS result 
    FROM test  

    UNION ALL 
    SELECT [3dist] AS dist, [3result] AS result 
    FROM test 
    ) AS a 
GROUP BY result 
HAVING (result = 'made')
```